# Can we use composition api variables inside JS file/class?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I want to use certain ref variables created in the composition API inside the JS class I am using.

But since inject/provide only work inside Vue files, I am not able to figure out how I can expose these ref variables inside the JS class files.

Don't see any such use cases in the documentation. Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this in the best possible way?

Comment: Surely it depends on what your *code* is trying to actually do